# Demonic pact and Harmless Offering

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I play [Demonic Pact](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDemonic%20Pact%5d) and then before my fourth upkeep, then just before I pass the turn I use [Harmless Offering](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHarmless%20Offering%5d) to give it to an opponent, what would happen?

Comment: There used to be decks using this very combo: https://www.mtggoldfish.com/articles/against-the-odds-harmless-pact-standard

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the basic question: can you make your opponent lose the game by "giving" them Demonic Pact after all but the last mode have been chosen?

Short answer: yes.

---

Demonic Pact's ability includes several uses of the words "you" and "your," which always refer to its controller.<sup>[109.5](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Control_and_Ownership)</sup>  Harmless Offering makes your opponent the controller of Demonic Pact, so they must now deal with the Pact during their upkeep.  This also means that "You lose the game" refers to *them* losing, regardless of who *used* to control the Pact.

Another question to ask at this point would be whether the previously chosen options are "reset" when the card changes controller.  The Gatherer rulings confirm that they do not:

> It doesn’t matter who has chosen any particular mode. For example, say you control Demonic Pact and have chosen the first two modes. If an opponent gains control of Demonic Pact, that player can choose only the third or fourth mode.

Putting all this together: if you can "use up" the first three modes of the Pact and then give it to your opponent, Demonic Pact's ability will require them to pick the only remaining mode and lose the game.

---

Note, however, that there are ways for your opponent to deal with your clever ploy.  They could, for example:

- Use a [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d) to eliminate Harmless Offering before it resolves.
- Destroy Demonic Pact using [Naturalize](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNaturalize%5d) during your end step.
- [Stifle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStifle%5d) Demonic Pact's ability before it can resolve.
- Use [Angel's Grace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngel%27s%5d%2b%5bGrace%5d) to prevent the Pact from making them lose.

All in all, though, it's going to be tricky for them to get out of this situation.  After seeing you play Harmless Offering, they'll certainly be wishing they could ignore the Gatherer rulings and "refuse your generous donation!"

Comment: They could also destroy the Pact, but it would have to be done at "instant speed".

Comment: @ikegami For clarity, they would need to do it before their upkeep; destroying it in response to the trigger would not help.

Comment: @ikegami Harmless Offering is a sorcery, so it would have to be played on your turn. You opponent would then have at least your end phase to respond to it.

Comment: Flicker also reset it, right?

Comment: @Acccumulation Flicker would do the same thing as destroying it.. as long as you do it before your upkeep, you will survive. But doing it in response to the trigger will not help.

Comment: @GendoIkari Destroying it gets rid of it. Flicker just delays it: you now have three turns of choosing something other than "lose the game".

Comment: @Acccumulation Of course... I was just referring to saving you from losing at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your opponent will lose, unless he has something that prevents him from losing, or a way to counter the triggered ability.

From the gatherer rulings for Demonic Pact:

> It doesn’t matter who has chosen any particular mode. For example, say you control Demonic Pact and have chosen the first two modes. If an opponent gains control of Demonic Pact, that player can choose only the third or fourth mode.

The key here is that changing control of an object does not cause it to become a new object in the same way that changing zones does. The Demonic Pact that your opponent has after you give it to him is the same one that you had.